# how to display one jFrame from the main Menu Jframe in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to open various jFrames from one Menu GUI form. I want display all the jFrames to be shown within this GUI form itself instead of opening the jFrame in a new window. how to display multiple jFrames within a single window in Swing?

Comment: Perhaps using JPanels as opposed to JFrames will let you accomplish what you want?

Comment: You're probably looking for [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  It shows many alternatives to multiple frames.

Comment: Got it, but provide me the required code for implementing this feature.